# Why am I getting: multiple definition of even though I use include gaurds

Tags: c++, header, linker

In `input.h` I define eventFunctions like so:

```
multimap <Uint8, function<void(SDL_Event&)>> eventFunctions;
```

Input.h is surrounded by:

```
#ifndef INPUT_H
#define INPUT_H
//code
#endif
```

However, on compilation I get this: `multiple definition of eventFunctions`
Referring to every file that includes `input.h`.
I also added this to input.h to see how many times it gets processed during compilation: `#warning "entered input_h"` The warning prints several times (every time it is included), showing that it is being processed more than once despite the include guards.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header file should contain declarations, not definitions. The definition should be in a single C++ file, not all of them. What you should do is have a single C++ file with this definition, and use an "extern" declaration in the header.

See this answer for more explanations:
[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c)